# Creating verticalized txt file with column for a and b in zip(a,b)

Tags: python

I'm creating a verticalized text file [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6ioX.png). Below is the portion of my code that is doing this using zip().

```
out = zip(word, pos)
outList = list(out)       
print(outList, file=output)
```

The problem I'm running into is that the format of outList is: ('it', 'PP'), ('was', 'VBD'), ('an', 'DT') How can I get my output to be formatted as verticalized text now that the words and parts of speech are matched up?

Answer (score 0):

You print it.  You just can't let Python's automatic formatting do it.

```
for line in zip(word,pos):
    print( "%10s %s" % line )
```